# Why does yii2 wants to logout through post method

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii and I was trying to create a simple authentication with the default behavior function in the site controller.

when done, I could login but could not logout and the error was shown:

```
Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.
```

Then I checked the controller and noticed:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

I changed the

```
'actions' => [
     'logout' => ['post'],
],
```

to

```
'actions' => [
     'logout' => ['get'],
],
```

and it worked fine.

I wonder what the concept behind this is and why would yii want to use post method for logout.

Answer (score 0):

Logout must be POST to be protected against [Cross-site request forgery](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/csrf/). The request should contain CSRF token. It can be obtained with:

```
Yii::$app->request->csrfParam
```